# How to get validation message in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-validation, laravel-5.5

hi folks I'm working on Laravel 5.5 and here I need to display validation messages for my API upto now I have done like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'first_name' => 'email|required',
            'last_name' => 'nullable',
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'mobile_no' => 'nullable|regex:/^[0-9]+$/',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        if($validator->fails)
        {
            $this->setMeta('status', AppConstant::STATUS_FAIL);
            $this->setMeta('message', $validator->messages()->first());
            return response()->json($this->setResponse(), AppConstant::UNPROCESSABLE_REQUEST);
        }
```

Since Laravel 5.5 has some awesome validation features I am looking to validate my request like this

```
request()->validate([
            'first_name' => 'email|required',
            'last_name' => 'nullable',
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'mobile_no' => 'nullable|regex:/^[0-9]+$/',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
```

But I am facing issue here what should I do to check if the validation fails? Like I was doing by `if($validator->fails)`

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validation-quickstart) it's explained there in the sections : **Displaying The Validation Errors** and **AJAX Requests & Validation** !!

Comment: I dont want to display them in view I need to send it back to mobile converting into `json()`

Comment: In the **AJAX Requests & Validation** section it is said : `Laravel generates a JSON response containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be sent with a 422 HTTP status code`

Comment: if u want your validation message , you can use this  return Response::json(array('success' => 0, 'msg'=> $validation->getMessageBag()->first()),200);

Comment: @Maraboc will this work with postman request? or on API request I am working on API not on AJAX bro

Comment: @GauravGupta Mm.. I am not using `$validator` here I am just passing the request directly.

Comment: Yes it will laravel test if it's a web or json request and then make the convenient response :)

Comment: that means you need to put your ifs to handle validation laravel will take care of them itself great!!

Comment: @Maraboc please post the answer so that I can close my question you can use my code for snippet :)

Comment: @Maraboc bro this answer doesnt worked for me apparently I found I need to use laravel FormRequest and for json I need to do customizing. :(

Answer (score 2):

In **Laravel 5.5**, like the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validation-quickstart) mention, the validation process is very easy :

- **Displaying The Validation Errors :**

> So, what if the incoming request parameters do not pass the given
>   validation rules? As mentioned previously, Laravel will automatically
>   redirect the user back to their previous location. In addition, all of
>   the validation errors will automatically be flashed to the session.
>
> Again, notice that we did not have to explicitly bind the error
>   messages to the view in our GET route. This is because Laravel will
>   check for errors in the session data, and automatically bind them to
>   the view if they are available.

- **AJAX Requests & Validation :**

> In this example, we used a traditional form to send data to the
>   application. However, many applications use AJAX requests. When using
>   the validate method during an AJAX request, Laravel will not generate
>   a redirect response. Instead, Laravel generates a JSON response
>   containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be
>   sent with a 422 HTTP status code.

So as you said : **that means you don't need to put your ifs to handle validation laravel will take care of them itself great** :)

Answer (score -1):

here is some syntax that i use

```
public static $user_rule = array(
'user_id'     => 'required',
'token' => 'required',
    );



public static function user($data)  
 {  
    try{
          $rules = User::$user_rule;
          $validation = validator::make($data,$rules);
          if($validation->passes())
          {


          }
          else
          {
              return Response::json(array('success' => 0, 'msg'=> $validation->getMessageBag()->first()),200);
          }
          return 1;
        }
    catch(\Illuminate\Databas\QueryException $e) {
            return Response::json(array('success' => 0, 'msg' => $e->getMessage()),200);
        }
 }
```

hope this will help you!

Answer (score -1):

Please add **Accept: application/json** in you header.

Laravel automatically send an error message with response code.

Answer (score -1):

As per 2019 Laravel 5.8 it is as easy as this:

```php
// create the validator and make a validation here...
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $fieldsWithErrorMessagesArray = $validator->messages()->get('*');
}
```

You will get the array of arrays of the fields' names and error messages.

Answer (score -1):

You can show first error.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
   $error = $validator->errors()->first();
}
```

For all error :

```
$validator->errors()
```