# Laravel 5.6 validator on ajax (api route) returns 200 instead of 422

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-validation, laravel-5.6

I am posting on Postman to my api route (in api.php) and when the data fails in validation, it returns me the errors in 200 response under this:

[image]

The above response is when I try:

```
{
    $valid = validator($request->only('email', 'password'), [
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
    ]);

    if ($valid->fails()) {
        $jsonError=response()->json($valid->errors()->all(), 400);
        return \Response::json($jsonError);
    }
}
```

---

However, when I try the one in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation) like below, it returns me to the view (laravel welcome page), something like `return back()`

```
 $request->validate([
     'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
     'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
 ]);
```

And the data I post is:

```
email: ''
password: ''

// also tried with and without header
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Not a Laravel expert but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487040/how-to-get-validation-message-in-laravel-5-5) and [other](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-send-validation-errors-as-json-to-view) might help you.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Yes, but weirdly, mine is not working for api.php routes. You can see in my below snippet, it's just like the one in docs; but it just returns me the view. However, I managed to make the upper one work with `return \Response::json($jsonError, 400);`. I am wondering why not the one shown in the 5.6 docs are working for me though

Comment: why not just `return response()->json($valid->errors()->all(), 400);`?

Comment: I was wondering why not the one shown in documentation not working (like my below snippet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is problematic.

```
$jsonError=response()->json($valid->errors()->all(), 400);
return \Response::json($jsonError);
```

`$jsonError` is already a JSONResponse object, then you've encapsulated it again inside a JSONReponse object.

The `json` method creates a new JSONResponse object, here is the underlying code.

```
public function json($data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = [], $options = 0)
{
    return new JsonResponse($data, $status, $headers, $options);
}
```

So, when you've pass `$jsonError` here, it was the `$data` argument. Now, `$status` argument has a default value of `200`, but you **DIDN'T** pass any, as per your code:

```
return \Response::json($jsonError);
//                               ^-- yeah, no $status argument here!
```

So it is correct that you will have a 200 response.

To fix your issue, just return the first JSONResponse object you've created.

```
return response()->json($valid->errors()->all(), 400);
```

If you still want to stick with your current code, then do this. But this is pointless.

```
$jsonError=response()->json($valid->errors()->all(), 400);
return \Response::json($jsonError, 400);
```

Also, `response()->json()` is just the same as `Response::json()` :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the Accept: application/json header ?

Please add **Accept: application/json** in you header.

Answer (score 0):

There is another reason for such behavior

in your validation rules you can use array for any input key instead of "|" separator

if it happened and mixed between array and "|" separator you will get always status code 200 instead of 422

example of wrong code:

```
'first_name' => [
    'bail',
    'required|string', // this should be replaced by 'required', 'string'
    'min:3',
    'max:15',
],
```